# Need to group by column while ignoring some text format

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have the following data.

```
Sport
--------------
Baseball
Football
Baseball [a]
Football [a] [b]
Basketball
```

How can I group this to ignore the data in the brackets?

Comment: Is your column a *char?

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
regexp_replace(the_column, ' +.*$', '')
```

will remove everything starting with the first space character up until the end of the string. So you just need to group by that expression:

```
with test_data (sport) as
(
  values 
    ('Baseball'), 
    ('Football'), 
    ('Baseball [a]'), 
    ('Football [a] [b]'), 
    ('Basketball')
)
select regexp_replace(sport, ' .*$', ''), count(*)
from test_data
group by regexp_replace(sport, ' .*$', '')
```

This will return:

```
regexp_replace | count
---------------+------
Baseball       |     2
Basketball     |     1
Football       |     2
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3379

**Edit**

To deal with legitimate multi-word sports there are two options:

1. remove everything after the first `[`: `regexp_replace(sport, ' \[.*$', '')`
2. remove all characters that occur between `[..]` and then trim the result: `trim(regexp_replace(sport, '\[.*\]', '', 'g'))`

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work with a sport that has two words.  How do use the regexp_replace to remove anything after the first bracket?

Comment: read my question: "How can I group this to ignore the data in the brackets."  I didn't say how do I ignore the data after the first space.

Answer (score -1):

```
USE tempdb 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP    TABLE #temp
GO
SELECT  Sport 
INTO    #temp 
FROM    (
            SELECT 'Baseball' Sport
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT 'Football'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Baseball [a]'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Football [a] [b]'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Basketball'
            )a

--Using CTE To Strip SpecialText
;WITH AvoidCertainText
AS
(
    SELECT  Sport
            , CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('[',Sport) <> 0 THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(Sport,CHARINDEX('[',Sport)-1)))
                ELSE Sport 
            END FormatedSport
    FROM    #temp 
)
SELECT   FormatedSport Sport
        , COUNT(FormatedSport)SportCount
FROM    AvoidCertainText 
GROUP BY FormatedSport
```

Comment: That is invalid SQL for Postgres. Plus: In Postgres the statement termination character (the `;`) needs to go at the _end_ of the statement.

Comment: This is a SQL Server answer to a Postgres question